# How to log extension header in postfix log?

Tags: postfix

I have postfix running as a relay server. In normal configuration, 
postfix does logging for "from" and "to" header. I would like postfix 
to log additional extension header eg. X-Mms-Originator-System and  X- 
Mms-3GPP-MMS-Version as example below.

Does anyone have any idea how to log this kind of extension header in 
postfix?

```
Date: Thu, 9 Feb 2012 15:33:09 +0700 (ICT) 
From: +66846462383/TYPE=PLMN 
Sender: +66846462383/TYPE=P...@grxmm4.happy.com 
To: +66815843236/TYPE=PLMN,+66892072043/TYPE=PLMN,+66838471846/TYPE=PLMN,+61434783265/TYPE=PLMN 
Message-ID: <542269348.734.1328776389955.JavaMail.root@mms-cmz-01> 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/smil"; start="<hISVa>"; .boundary="----=_Part_34_1141875874.1328776389677" 
X-Mms-Originator-System: m...@grxmm4.happy.com 
X-Mms-3GPP-MMS-Version: 6.5.0
```

Comment: Actually, Postfix generally won't log the From and To headers from your email content.  What it logs are the addresses used in the SMTP Envelope, which may be different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [header check](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) with the [WARN target](http://www.seaglass.com/postfix/faq.html#lgsbj), this will log your header.

```
## main.cf
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

## header_checks
/^X-Mms-Originator-System: / WARN
```

should work

Comment: I had to remove the blank between ^ and X to make it work.

Comment: INFO also works for me (Ubuntu 18.04).