# How to show/include originating domain/application in Postfix logs

Tags: linux, postfix, drupal

I have a server which hosts a number of applications mostly built with Drupal. These applications are configured to send mails and Postfix is my MTA.

Is it possible to have the applications and/or Postfix configured to identify in its log [maillog] which application or domain a mail originates from?

So for example, if I have applications/domains: a.com b.com and c.com, is it possible to show these against each mail in /var/log/maillog? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of identifying the webapp that delivered mail to your MTA:

- sendmail UID: if you use the local sendmail utility to deliver mail to postfix, there will be a `uid=312` present in your logs. Use different system users for you webapps so different uid's will show up in your logs.
- the postfix qmgr should log the FROM address in the form of `from=<mail@example.com>` - that can help you differentiate.
- you can use PHPs mail() `additional_headers` option to simply add the domain to your mail headers and use postfix [header_checks](https://serverfault.com/questions/392838/how-to-log-extension-header-in-postfix-log) to log you custom header.