# How to tell how many users are sending/receiving encrypted email in Postfix/Dovecot?

Tags: postfix

I have access to the /var/log/mail.log files. They also output to Splunk. How do I find out how many users are sending/receiving encrypted email in Postfix/Dovecot? They use Enigmail/PGP in their Thunderbird clients.

Answer (score 3):

Standard `mail.log` generated by `postfix` doesn't contain information about email content and it is impossible to determine whether an email was encrypted by a MUA.

Comment: Ah ok, not even via mail headers? Sorry what's MUA?

Comment: The only header logged is `message-id`. MUA is Mail User Agent. Thunderbird is a MUA.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if you are violating privacy by probing the content of emails, then you need to tell Postfix to [log the Content-Type header](https://serverfault.com/questions/392838/how-to-log-extension-header-in-postfix-log).

I don't know what content-type value Enigmail uses, it is likely one of X-PGP-Encoding-Format or X-PGP-Encoding-Version.

You might want to explicity set these in the Postfix header regexes.

Comment: BTW, [Enigmail isn't supported anymore](https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/home/news/71-2021-08-31-end-of-support-for-thunderbird) as Thunderbird [since 78](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-thunderbird-howto-and-faq#w_does-thunderbird-support-openpgp) supports PGP natively.