# PHP mail.add_x_header not showing in log

Tags: php, email, web-server

On Ubuntu 22.04 I have the following in `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` (and have restarted Apache), and in `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`:

```
; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On
```

When I send a mail from a PHP script like this:

```
<?php
mail('myaddress@gmail.com','Test message subject','Test message body');
echo 'Mail sent.'; 
?>
```

It sends and arrives all OK, but there is no mention of any `X-PHP-Originating-Script` in any log I can find. I have tried setting the `mail.log =` directive in php.ini to the default, as well as to `syslog` and to a file in `/tmp`.

When I run `phpinfo();` it confirms the settings are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**: If I look at the mail headers I receive, I see the `X-PHP-Originating-Script:` line in there. Perhaps I've misunderstood - is that all the php.ini directive does?

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: If I look at the mail headers I receive, I see the X-PHP-Originating-Script: line in there. Perhaps I've misunderstood - is that all the php.ini directive does?

Yes. As indicated by the fact that it's named `mail.x-add-header`. You can probably [configure your mailserver to log this to file if you want](https://serverfault.com/questions/392838/how-to-log-extension-header-in-postfix-log).

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I had assumed the line under it `mail.log =` was where the name of the script would be logged, but obviously not as that seems to do nothing.

Comment: That's a separate setting - have a look at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log). Whilst a lot can be said about PHP, the documentation is fairly good.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it's not logging mail calls is I suppose another issue. But if I can do it with postfix `header_checks` then that's fine I think.